# iOS:add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to UIWebView

Tags: ios

I want add UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to UIWebView,but failed.

if [self.view addsubView:webView];
So UIWebView is ok,but not UIGestureRecognizerDelegate..

if remove [self.view addsubView:webView];
So UIGestureRecognizerDelegate is ok,but view nothing at all.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

webView= [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, -2.0f, 320.0f, 415.0f)];

if (_refreshHeaderView == nil) {
    webScroller = (UIScrollView *)[[webView subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    [webScroller setDelegate:self];

    EGORefreshTableHeaderView *view = [[EGORefreshTableHeaderView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f - webScroller.bounds.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, webScroller.bounds.size.height)];
    view.delegate = self;
    [webScroller addSubview:view];
    _refreshHeaderView = view;
}

[_refreshHeaderView refreshLastUpdatedDate];

[self.view addSubview:self.webView];


// Set up recognizers.
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add the Gesture Recognizer to the webView and not the main view of your application which is under the webView, after you add your webView as a subView to the main View, then you should change your "addGestureRecognizer" like this...

```
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2;
doubleTapRecognizer.delegate =self;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTapRecognizer];
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] 
                                               initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleGesture:)];
tapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
tapRecognizer.delegate = self;
[self.webView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
```

Then as this is a UIWebView you should also conform to the protocol **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** in your header file and then return YES from the following methods.  This way the UIWebView gestures and your own will both be handled, otherwise yours will be hidden by the UIWebView's own recognizers.

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{
return YES;}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
return YES;}
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch{
return YES;}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried, but no effect, I think is UIWebView default gestures conflict.Thank you.

Comment: Yes you are right.  I just improved the answer and this should now work if you implement the UIGestureRecognizerDelegate methods mentioned above.